# How to disable input history in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm capturing sensitive information on the main page of my Django project.
Is there a way to prevent the previous login info from showing when a user clicks or starts typing in the box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable autocomplete on such fields by setting the HTML5 `autocomplete` attribute to `off`. To achieve this in Django's forms you need to pass additional information to the widget for each input, e.g.:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    secret = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}))
```